# Why is the sky bright orange in my Olympus camera's viewfinder?

Tags: color, olympus, evf

Hi all I have an Olympus EM 10 and I have an issue with strange colours when I take a picture. The blue sky for example is bright orange. The pictures are fine though it's just the viewfinder and the screen and when I view them on the camera or after on my I pad all is as it should be. 
Can anyone please tell me why.

Answer (score 2):

The viewfinder is telling you that you've overexposed the sky. You may be able to turn that feature on and off. I briefly skimmed [the manual](http://www.olympus.co.jp/en/support/imsg/digicamera/download/manual/omd/man_em10_e.pdf) but was unable to find the feature. You may have better luck.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I think there must be a setting somewhere because it didn't used to to this. I will check it out. Thanks again

Comment: Tap the "info" button. It's called Highlights&Shadows.

Answer (score 1):

Your camera is telling you what part of the scene is the brightest. How bright is bright enough to be included in the display's warning can be adjusted by the user. Page numbers in the following paragraph refer to the [*EM-10 Instruction Manual*](http://www.olympus.co.jp/en/support/imsg/digicamera/download/manual/omd/man_em10_e.pdf).

You can use the *Multi-function* button (p. 23) to select *Highlight & Shadow Control* (p.50). You can then adjust the parameters for the *Highlight & Shadow Control* by pressing the *Fn2* button and rotating the rear dial for shadows and the front dial for highlights (p. 50). See page 10 for the location of each of the referenced buttons.